# Why i have empty result SPARQL query?

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, protege

My query to Protege in SPARQL:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT * WHERE {
?a rdfs:SubClassOf <http://www.semanticweb.org/ugrobug/ontologies/2021/2/untitled-ontology-16/Rock>;
}
```

Check ontology. It's have this data:

```
<SubClassOf>
        <Class IRI="#Symphonic_rock"/>
        <Class IRI="#Rock"/>
  </SubClassOf>
```

Why i have empty results?

Whole ontology https://drive.google.com/file/d/18L6LU-PW_R-JmKC9YfrMXWPY3RJ6B4TF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: it's case-sensitive: `rdfs:subClassOf` - you have to look at the N-Triples or Turtle syntax of RDF which is what the SPARQL syntax is basically based on

Comment: Ichange it but not have some new result

Comment: what do you mean by "not have some new result" - does it mean you don't get any data at all or not the result you expect? If so, what do you get and what do you expect? The query will in fact return data if there is any proper subclass relation in your ontology. Without seeing your data, no way to give further help

Comment: it's part of my data:  <SubClassOf>
        <Class IRI="#Symphonic_rock"/>
        <Class IRI="#Rock"/>
    </SubClassOf>     I want to system sent to me result "Symphonic_rock"

Comment: please check the URI of `http://www.semanticweb.org/ugrobug/ontologies/2021/2/untitled-ontology-16/Rock` - maybe it's not correct and should be `http://www.semanticweb.org/ugrobug/ontologies/2021/2/untitled-ontology-16#Rock`. Or please post the whole dataset by editing your question.

Comment: My whole ontology https://drive.google.com/file/d/18L6LU-PW_R-JmKC9YfrMXWPY3RJ6B4TF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: as I said, check the base prefix declaration is `http://www.semanticweb.org/ugrobug/ontologies/2021/2/untitled-ontology-16` and then the classes are `#Rock` - thus, the URI is `http://www.semanticweb.org/ugrobug/ontologies/2021/2/untitled-ontology-16#Rock`